# Cant create or edit item with Office 2016 for Mac (El Capitan) on SharePoint 2013 site!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, word, mac-os-x

I am having some problems creating and editing documents on a SharePoint 2013 site on a upgraded Mac (El Capitan) and with Office 2016. When I try to create a new document, or edit, I get the notification that “*The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document* “.

I have tried reinstall Office.

Googled and found out that Office 2016 for Mac may not have the SharePointBrowserPlugin and SharePointWebKitPlugin. So I tried copying the files from a Office 2011 for Mac. But still not working.

When I check Safari Security Plugin setting I can see that SharePoint Browser Plugin is listed and given the permission “Allow” for the SharePoint site (regardless Office 2011 or 2016).

I also checked for the plugin files with a new Office 2016 installation, and apparently they are there.

**Note: When I only have Office 2011 installed, all works fine! and I can create/edit a new file and it opens in Word!**

**UPDATE:**

If I have Office 2011 and 2016 installed, I get the properties when only 2011 was installed. So now, I can create a new document (from content type) or edit it, and when the document opens, it opens in Word 2016!

However, this should not be necessary and a fix should come from Apple and/or Microsoft.

Nevertheless, if someone knows a workaround or a fix so that only Office 2016 needs to be installed, I still want to know!